# getting column Heading names in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me in this 
consider a table in oracle Database

```
SNo Name password
------------------
1    x    1234
2    y    2314
```

A query to  fetch the headings such as SNO NAME PASSWORD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query `user_tab_columns` (or `all_tab_columns`) to get the column names:

```
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
```

Replace `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` with your actual table name.

See for more info:
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4462.htm#REFRN26277

Comment: can you please elaborate little bit about user_tab_columns

Comment: @raghuram - Added a link for you.

Comment: i didnt get output i got a blank space . i just would like to know what can i add at user_tab_columns

Comment: @raghuram - Replace YOUR_TABLE_NAME with your actual table name.

Comment: I'm using a custom user, so in my case was needed to change "user_tab_columns" to "all_tab_columns" but this awnser help me alot